# ASP Parser Select Specific XML Return Values - FedEx Web Services

Tags: xml, asp-classic, fedex

I am trying to return only one specific rate set from the FedEx Web Service Rate Reply (XML). The Rate Reply Returns several rate types in multiple sets and I am only currently able to return the first set.

This is the current code that grabs the first set of results.

```
set xml = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
xml.open "POST", "https://ws.fedex.com:443/web-services"
xml.send soapEnvelope

set parser = xml.responseXML
set rates = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

for each item in parser.SelectNodes("//RateReplyDetails")
    rates.add item.SelectSingleNode("ServiceType").text, item.SelectSingleNode("RatedShipmentDetails[0]").SelectSingleNode("ShipmentRateDetail").SelectSingleNode("TotalNetCharge").text
next

set GetFedExRates = rates
```

Here is an example of the rate request. What I need for data is the **TotalNetCharge** under `<v4:ActualRateType>PAYOR_LIST</v4:ActualRateType>`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <v4:RateReply xmlns:rate="http://fedex.com/ws/rate/v5" xmlns:v4="http://fedex.com/ws/rate/v4">

            <ns1:TransactionDetail xmlns:ns1="http://fedex.com/ws/rate/v4" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
                <ns1:CustomerTransactionId> *** Rate Request v4 using PHP ***</ns1:CustomerTransactionId>
            </ns1:TransactionDetail>
            <ns1:Version xmlns:ns1="http://fedex.com/ws/rate/v4" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
                <ns1:ServiceId>crs</ns1:ServiceId>
                <ns1:Major>4</ns1:Major>
                <ns1:Intermediate>0</ns1:Intermediate>
                <ns1:Minor>0</ns1:Minor>
            </ns1:Version>
            <v4:RateReplyDetails>
                <v4:ServiceType>PRIORITY_OVERNIGHT</v4:ServiceType>
                <v4:PackagingType>YOUR_PACKAGING</v4:PackagingType>
                <v4:IneligibleForMoneyBackGuarantee>false</v4:IneligibleForMoneyBackGuarantee>
                <v4:OriginServiceArea>A1</v4:OriginServiceArea>
                <v4:DestinationServiceArea>A1</v4:DestinationServiceArea>
                <v4:SignatureOption>SERVICE_DEFAULT</v4:SignatureOption>
                <v4:ActualRateType>PAYOR_ACCOUNT</v4:ActualRateType>
                <v4:RatedShipmentDetails>
                    <v4:EffectiveNetDiscount>
                        <v4:Currency>USD</v4:Currency>
                        <v4:Amount>28.02</v4:Amount>
                    </v4:EffectiveNetDiscount>
                    <v4:ShipmentRateDetail>
                        <v4:RateType>PAYOR_ACCOUNT</v4:RateType>
                        <v4:RateScale>1</v4:RateScale>
                        <v4:PricingCode>PACKAGE</v4:PricingCode>
                        <v4:DimDivisor>194</v4:DimDivisor>
                        <v4:FuelSurchargePercent>16.5</v4:FuelSurchargePercent>
                        <v4:TotalBillingWeight>
                            <v4:Units>LB</v4:Units>
                            <v4:Value>13.0</v4:Value>
                        </v4:TotalBillingWeight>
                        <v4:TotalDimWeight>
                            <v4:Units>LB</v4:Units>
                            <v4:Value>13.0</v4:Value>
                        </v4:TotalDimWeight>
                        <v4:TotalBaseCharge>
                            <v4:Currency>USD</v4:Currency>
                            <v4:Amount>52.25</v4:Amount>
                        </v4:TotalBaseCharge>
                        <v4:TotalFreightDiscounts>
                            <v4:Currency>USD</v4:Currency>
                            <v4:Amount>0.0</v4:Amount>
                        </v4:TotalFreightDiscounts>
                        <v4:TotalNetFreight>
                            <v4:Currency>USD</v4:Currency>
                            <v4:Amount>52.25</v4:Amount>
                        </v4:TotalNetFreight>
                        <v4:TotalSurcharges>
                            <v4:Currency>USD</v4:Currency>
                            <v4:Amount>8.62</v4:Amount>
                        </v4:TotalSurcharges>
                        <v4:TotalNetFedExCharge>
                            <v4:Currency>USD</v4:Currency>
                            <v4:Amount>60.87</v4:Amount>
                        </v4:TotalNetFedExCharge>
                        <v4:TotalTaxes>
                            <v4:Currency>USD</v4:Currency>
                            <v4:Amount>0.0</v4:Amount>
                        </v4:TotalTaxes>
                        <v4:TotalNetCharge>
                            <v4:Currency>USD</v4:Currency>
                            <v4:Amount>60.87</v4:Amount>
                        </v4:TotalNetCharge>
                        <v4:TotalRebates>
                            <v4:Currency>USD</v4:Currency>
                            <v4:Amount>0.0</v4:Amount>
                        </v4:TotalRebates>
                        <v4:Surcharges>
                            <v4:SurchargeType>INSURED_VALUE</v4:SurchargeType>
                            <v4:Description>Insured value</v4:Description>
                            <v4:Amount>
                                <v4:Currency>USD</v4:Currency>
                                <v4:Amount>0.0</v4:Amount>
                            </v4:Amount>
                        </v4:Surcharges>
                        <v4:Surcharges>
                            <v4:SurchargeType>FUEL</v4:SurchargeType>
                            <v4:Description>Fuel</v4:Description>
                            <v4:Amount>
                                <v4:Currency>USD</v4:Currency>
                                <v4:Amount>8.62</v4:Amount>
                            </v4:Amount>
                        </v4:Surcharges>
                    </v4:ShipmentRateDetail>
                    <v4:RatedPackages>
                        <v4:EffectiveNetDiscount>
                            <v4:Currency>USD</v4:Currency>
                            <v4:Amount>28.02</v4:Amount>
                        </v4:EffectiveNetDiscount>
                        <v4:PackageRateDetail>
                            <v4:RateType>PAYOR_ACCOUNT</v4:RateType>
                            <v4:RatedWeightMethod>DIM</v4:RatedWeightMethod>
                            <v4:BillingWeight>
                                <v4:Units>LB</v4:Units>
                                <v4:Value>13.0</v4:Value>
                            </v4:BillingWeight>
                            <v4:DimWeight>
                                <v4:Units>LB</v4:Units>
                                <v4:Value>13.0</v4:Value>
                            </v4:DimWeight>
                            <v4:BaseCharge>
                                <v4:Currency>USD</v4:Currency>
                                <v4:Amount>52.25</v4:Amount>
                            </v4:BaseCharge>
                            <v4:TotalFreightDiscounts>
                                <v4:Currency>USD</v4:Currency>
                                <v4:Amount>0.0</v4:Amount>
                            </v4:TotalFreightDiscounts>
                            <v4:NetFreight>
                                <v4:Currency>USD</v4:Currency>
                                <v4:Amount>52.25</v4:Amount>
                            </v4:NetFreight>
                            <v4:TotalSurcharges>
                                <v4:Currency>USD</v4:Currency>
                                <v4:Amount>8.62</v4:Amount>
                            </v4:TotalSurcharges>
                            <v4:NetFedExCharge>
                                <v4:Currency>USD</v4:Currency>
                                <v4:Amount>60.87</v4:Amount>
                            </v4:NetFedExCharge>
                            <v4:TotalTaxes>
                                <v4:Currency>USD</v4:Currency>
                                <v4:Amount>0.0</v4:Amount>
                            </v4:TotalTaxes>
                            <v4:NetCharge>
                                <v4:Currency>USD</v4:Currency>
                                <v4:Amount>60.87</v4:Amount>
                            </v4:NetCharge>
                            <v4:TotalRebates>
                                <v4:Currency>USD</v4:Currency>
                                <v4:Amount>0.0</v4:Amount>
                            </v4:TotalRebates>
                            <v4:Surcharges>
                                <v4:SurchargeType>INSURED_VALUE</v4:SurchargeType>
                                <v4:Description>Insured value</v4:Description>
                                <v4:Amount>
                                    <v4:Currency>USD</v4:Currency>
                                    <v4:Amount>0.0</v4:Amount>
                                </v4:Amount>
                            </v4:Surcharges>
                            <v4:Surcharges>
                                <v4:SurchargeType>FUEL</v4:SurchargeType>
                                <v4:Description>Fuel</v4:Description>
                                <v4:Amount>
                                    <v4:Currency>USD</v4:Currency>
                                    <v4:Amount>8.62</v4:Amount>
                                </v4:Amount>
                            </v4:Surcharges>
                        </v4:PackageRateDetail>
                    </v4:RatedPackages>
                </v4:RatedShipmentDetails>
                <v4:RatedShipmentDetails>
                    <v4:EffectiveNetDiscount>
                        <v4:Currency>USD</v4:Currency>
                        <v4:Amount>28.02</v4:Amount>
                    </v4:EffectiveNetDiscount>
                    <v4:ShipmentRateDetail>
                        <v4:RateType>RATED_ACCOUNT</v4:RateType>
                        <v4:RateScale>1</v4:RateScale>
                        <v4:PricingCode>PACKAGE</v4:PricingCode>
                        <v4:DimDivisor>194</v4:DimDivisor>
                        <v4:FuelSurchargePercent>16.5</v4:FuelSurchargePercent>
                        <v4:TotalBillingWeight>
                            <v4:Units>LB</v4:Units>
                            <v4:Value>13.0</v4:Value>
                        </v4:TotalBillingWeight>
                        <v4:TotalDimWeight>
                            <v4:Units>LB</v4:Units>
                            <v4:Value>13.0</v4:Value>
                        </v4:TotalDimWeight>
                        <v4:TotalBaseCharge>
                            <v4:Currency>USD</v4:Currency>
                            <v4:Amount>52.25</v4:Amount>
                        </v4:TotalBaseCharge>
                        <v4:TotalFreightDiscounts>
                            <v4:Currency>USD</v4:Currency>
                            <v4:Amount>0.0</v4:Amount>
                        </v4:TotalFreightDiscounts>
                        <v4:TotalNetFreight>
                            <v4:Currency>USD</v4:Currency>
                            <v4:Amount>52.25</v4:Amount>
                        </v4:TotalNetFreight>
                        <v4:TotalSurcharges>
                            <v4:Currency>USD</v4:Currency>
                            <v4:Amount>8.62</v4:Amount>
                        </v4:TotalSurcharges>
                        <v4:TotalNetFedExCharge>
                            <v4:Currency>USD</v4:Currency>
                            <v4:Amount>60.87</v4:Amount>
                        </v4:TotalNetFedExCharge>
                        <v4:TotalTaxes>
                            <v4:Currency>USD</v4:Currency>
                            <v4:Amount>0.0</v4:Amount>
                        </v4:TotalTaxes>
                        <v4:TotalNetCharge>
                            <v4:Currency>USD</v4:Currency>
                            <v4:Amount>60.87</v4:Amount>
                        </v4:TotalNetCharge>
                        <v4:TotalRebates>
                            <v4:Currency>USD</v4:Currency>
                            <v4:Amount>0.0</v4:Amount>
                        </v4:TotalRebates>
                        <v4:Surcharges>
                            <v4:SurchargeType>INSURED_VALUE</v4:SurchargeType>
                            <v4:Description>Insured value</v4:Description>
                            <v4:Amount>
                                <v4:Currency>USD</v4:Currency>
                                <v4:Amount>0.0</v4:Amount>
                            </v4:Amount>
                        </v4:Surcharges>
                        <v4:Surcharges>
                            <v4:SurchargeType>FUEL</v4:SurchargeType>
                            <v4:Description>Fuel</v4:Description>
                            <v4:Amount>
                                <v4:Currency>USD</v4:Currency>
                                <v4:Amount>8.62</v4:Amount>
                            </v4:Amount>
                        </v4:Surcharges>
                    </v4:ShipmentRateDetail>
                    <v4:RatedPackages>
                        <v4:EffectiveNetDiscount>
                            <v4:Currency>USD</v4:Currency>
                            <v4:Amount>28.02</v4:Amount>
                        </v4:EffectiveNetDiscount>
                        <v4:PackageRateDetail>
                            <v4:RateType>RATED_ACCOUNT</v4:RateType>
                            <v4:RatedWeightMethod>DIM</v4:RatedWeightMethod>
                            <v4:BillingWeight>
                                <v4:Units>LB</v4:Units>
                                <v4:Value>13.0</v4:Value>
                            </v4:BillingWeight>
                            <v4:DimWeight>
                                <v4:Units>LB</v4:Units>
                                <v4:Value>13.0</v4:Value>
                            </v4:DimWeight>
                            <v4:BaseCharge>
                                <v4:Currency>USD</v4:Currency>
                                <v4:Amount>52.25</v4:Amount>
                            </v4:BaseCharge>
                            <v4:TotalFreightDiscounts>
                                <v4:Currency>USD</v4:Currency>
                                <v4:Amount>0.0</v4:Amount>
                            </v4:TotalFreightDiscounts>
                            <v4:NetFreight>
                                <v4:Currency>USD</v4:Currency>
                                <v4:Amount>52.25</v4:Amount>
                            </v4:NetFreight>
                            <v4:TotalSurcharges>
                                <v4:Currency>USD</v4:Currency>
                                <v4:Amount>8.62</v4:Amount>
                            </v4:TotalSurcharges>
                            <v4:NetFedExCharge>
                                <v4:Currency>USD</v4:Currency>
                                <v4:Amount>60.87</v4:Amount>
                            </v4:NetFedExCharge>
                            <v4:TotalTaxes>
                                <v4:Currency>USD</v4:Currency>
                                <v4:Amount>0.0</v4:Amount>
                            </v4:TotalTaxes>
                            <v4:NetCharge>
                                <v4:Currency>USD</v4:Currency>
                                <v4:Amount>60.87</v4:Amount>
                            </v4:NetCharge>
                            <v4:TotalRebates>
                                <v4:Currency>USD</v4:Currency>
                                <v4:Amount>0.0</v4:Amount>
                            </v4:TotalRebates>
                            <v4:Surcharges>
                                <v4:SurchargeType>INSURED_VALUE</v4:SurchargeType>
                                <v4:Description>Insured value</v4:Description>
                                <v4:Amount>
                                    <v4:Currency>USD</v4:Currency>
                                    <v4:Amount>0.0</v4:Amount>
                                </v4:Amount>
                            </v4:Surcharges>
                            <v4:Surcharges>
                                <v4:SurchargeType>FUEL</v4:SurchargeType>
                                <v4:Description>Fuel</v4:Description>
                                <v4:Amount>
                                    <v4:Currency>USD</v4:Currency>
                                    <v4:Amount>8.62</v4:Amount>
                                </v4:Amount>
                            </v4:Surcharges>
                        </v4:PackageRateDetail>
                    </v4:RatedPackages>
                </v4:RatedShipmentDetails>
                <v4:RatedShipmentDetails>
                    <v4:ShipmentRateDetail>
                        <v4:RateType>PAYOR_LIST</v4:RateType>
                        <v4:RateScale>1552</v4:RateScale>
                        <v4:RateZone>5</v4:RateZone>
                        <v4:PricingCode>PACKAGE</v4:PricingCode>
                        <v4:DimDivisor>194</v4:DimDivisor>
                        <v4:FuelSurchargePercent>16.5</v4:FuelSurchargePercent>
                        <v4:TotalBillingWeight>
                            <v4:Units>LB</v4:Units>
                            <v4:Value>13.0</v4:Value>
                        </v4:TotalBillingWeight>
                        <v4:TotalDimWeight>
                            <v4:Units>LB</v4:Units>
                            <v4:Value>13.0</v4:Value>
                        </v4:TotalDimWeight>
                        <v4:TotalBaseCharge>
                            <v4:Currency>USD</v4:Currency>
                            <v4:Amount>76.3</v4:Amount>
                        </v4:TotalBaseCharge>
                        <v4:TotalFreightDiscounts>
                            <v4:Currency>USD</v4:Currency>
                            <v4:Amount>0.0</v4:Amount>
                        </v4:TotalFreightDiscounts>
                        <v4:TotalNetFreight>
                            <v4:Currency>USD</v4:Currency>
                            <v4:Amount>76.3</v4:Amount>
                        </v4:TotalNetFreight>
                        <v4:TotalSurcharges>
                            <v4:Currency>USD</v4:Currency>
                            <v4:Amount>12.59</v4:Amount>
                        </v4:TotalSurcharges>
                        <v4:TotalNetFedExCharge>
                            <v4:Currency>USD</v4:Currency>
                            <v4:Amount>88.89</v4:Amount>
                        </v4:TotalNetFedExCharge>
                        <v4:TotalTaxes>
                            <v4:Currency>USD</v4:Currency>
                            <v4:Amount>0.0</v4:Amount>
                        </v4:TotalTaxes>
                        <v4:TotalNetCharge>
                            <v4:Currency>USD</v4:Currency>
                            <v4:Amount>88.89</v4:Amount>
                        </v4:TotalNetCharge>
                        <v4:TotalRebates>
                            <v4:Currency>USD</v4:Currency>
                            <v4:Amount>0.0</v4:Amount>
                        </v4:TotalRebates>
                        <v4:Surcharges>
                            <v4:SurchargeType>INSURED_VALUE</v4:SurchargeType>
                            <v4:Description>Insured value</v4:Description>
                            <v4:Amount>
                                <v4:Currency>USD</v4:Currency>
                                <v4:Amount>0.0</v4:Amount>
                            </v4:Amount>
                        </v4:Surcharges>
                        <v4:Surcharges>
                            <v4:SurchargeType>FUEL</v4:SurchargeType>
                            <v4:Description>Fuel</v4:Description>
                            <v4:Amount>
                                <v4:Currency>USD</v4:Currency>
                                <v4:Amount>12.59</v4:Amount>
                            </v4:Amount>
                        </v4:Surcharges>
                    </v4:ShipmentRateDetail>
                    <v4:RatedPackages>
                        <v4:PackageRateDetail>
                            <v4:RateType>PAYOR_LIST</v4:RateType>
                            <v4:RatedWeightMethod>DIM</v4:RatedWeightMethod>
                            <v4:BillingWeight>
                                <v4:Units>LB</v4:Units>
                                <v4:Value>13.0</v4:Value>
                            </v4:BillingWeight>
                            <v4:DimWeight>
                                <v4:Units>LB</v4:Units>
                                <v4:Value>13.0</v4:Value>
                            </v4:DimWeight>
                            <v4:BaseCharge>
                                <v4:Currency>USD</v4:Currency>
                                <v4:Amount>76.3</v4:Amount>
                            </v4:BaseCharge>
                            <v4:TotalFreightDiscounts>
                                <v4:Currency>USD</v4:Currency>
                                <v4:Amount>0.0</v4:Amount>
                            </v4:TotalFreightDiscounts>
                            <v4:NetFreight>
                                <v4:Currency>USD</v4:Currency>
                                <v4:Amount>76.3</v4:Amount>
                            </v4:NetFreight>
                            <v4:TotalSurcharges>
                                <v4:Currency>USD</v4:Currency>
                                <v4:Amount>12.59</v4:Amount>
                            </v4:TotalSurcharges>
                            <v4:NetFedExCharge>
                                <v4:Currency>USD</v4:Currency>
                                <v4:Amount>88.89</v4:Amount>
                            </v4:NetFedExCharge>
                            <v4:TotalTaxes>
                                <v4:Currency>USD</v4:Currency>
                                <v4:Amount>0.0</v4:Amount>
                            </v4:TotalTaxes>
                            <v4:NetCharge>
                                <v4:Currency>USD</v4:Currency>
                                <v4:Amount>88.89</v4:Amount>
                            </v4:NetCharge>
                            <v4:TotalRebates>
                                <v4:Currency>USD</v4:Currency>
                                <v4:Amount>0.0</v4:Amount>
                            </v4:TotalRebates>
                            <v4:Surcharges>
                                <v4:SurchargeType>INSURED_VALUE</v4:SurchargeType>
                                <v4:Description>Insured value</v4:Description>
                                <v4:Amount>
                                    <v4:Currency>USD</v4:Currency>
                                    <v4:Amount>0.0</v4:Amount>
                                </v4:Amount>
                            </v4:Surcharges>
                            <v4:Surcharges>
                                <v4:SurchargeType>FUEL</v4:SurchargeType>
                                <v4:Description>Fuel</v4:Description>
                                <v4:Amount>
                                    <v4:Currency>USD</v4:Currency>
                                    <v4:Amount>12.59</v4:Amount>
                                </v4:Amount>
                            </v4:Surcharges>
                        </v4:PackageRateDetail>
                    </v4:RatedPackages>
                </v4:RatedShipmentDetails>
                <v4:RatedShipmentDetails>
                    <v4:ShipmentRateDetail>
                        <v4:RateType>RATED_LIST</v4:RateType>
                        <v4:RateScale>1552</v4:RateScale>
                        <v4:RateZone>5</v4:RateZone>
                        <v4:PricingCode>PACKAGE</v4:PricingCode>
                        <v4:DimDivisor>194</v4:DimDivisor>
                        <v4:FuelSurchargePercent>16.5</v4:FuelSurchargePercent>
                        <v4:TotalBillingWeight>
                            <v4:Units>LB</v4:Units>
                            <v4:Value>13.0</v4:Value>
                        </v4:TotalBillingWeight>
                        <v4:TotalDimWeight>
                            <v4:Units>LB</v4:Units>
                            <v4:Value>13.0</v4:Value>
                        </v4:TotalDimWeight>
                        <v4:TotalBaseCharge>
                            <v4:Currency>USD</v4:Currency>
                            <v4:Amount>76.3</v4:Amount>
                        </v4:TotalBaseCharge>
                        <v4:TotalFreightDiscounts>
                            <v4:Currency>USD</v4:Currency>
                            <v4:Amount>0.0</v4:Amount>
                        </v4:TotalFreightDiscounts>
                        <v4:TotalNetFreight>
                            <v4:Currency>USD</v4:Currency>
                            <v4:Amount>76.3</v4:Amount>
                        </v4:TotalNetFreight>
                        <v4:TotalSurcharges>
                            <v4:Currency>USD</v4:Currency>
                            <v4:Amount>12.59</v4:Amount>
                        </v4:TotalSurcharges>
                        <v4:TotalNetFedExCharge>
                            <v4:Currency>USD</v4:Currency>
                            <v4:Amount>88.89</v4:Amount>
                        </v4:TotalNetFedExCharge>
                        <v4:TotalTaxes>
                            <v4:Currency>USD</v4:Currency>
                            <v4:Amount>0.0</v4:Amount>
                        </v4:TotalTaxes>
                        <v4:TotalNetCharge>
                            <v4:Currency>USD</v4:Currency>
                            <v4:Amount>88.89</v4:Amount>
                        </v4:TotalNetCharge>
                        <v4:TotalRebates>
                            <v4:Currency>USD</v4:Currency>
                            <v4:Amount>0.0</v4:Amount>
                        </v4:TotalRebates>
                        <v4:Surcharges>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick example I tested using the Rate Reply XML from [here](http://www.fedex.com/us/developer/product/WebServices/MyWebHelp_Oct08/Content/NewImport/Rate_Reply.htm). It should provide guidance on how to implement it in your case.

```
set xml = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
xml.Load "fedex.xml"

set rates = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

for each item in xml.SelectNodes("//rate:RateReplyDetails")
    serviceType = item.SelectSingleNode("rate:ServiceType").text
    netCharge = item.SelectSingleNode("rate:RatedShipmentDetails/rate:ShipmentRateDetail/rate:TotalNetCharge/rate:Amount").text

    Wscript.Echo "ServiceType " & serviceType & vbCrlF
    Wscript.Echo "TotalNedCharge " & netCharge & vbCrlF

    rates.add serviceType, netCharge
next
```

Comment: I am running into several errors when sending the soap request and loading the soap request.  Your example is loading a local file (fedex.xml).  How could I use a soap request instead?

Comment: I am not having problems with sending the soap request.  

When I add "rate:" after the "//", the results are blank.

Comment: The namespace in the example I used was "rate". Change it to "v4" for your case. I will update the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks for specifying that.  I am still unable to select the rate specified as "PAYOR_LIST_PACKAGE".  The first that comes up is the rate for "PAYOR_ACCOUNT_PACKAGE".  How can I edit the "netCharge" to reflect the price for PAYOR_LIST_PACKAGE?  Thanks again!

Comment: netCharge = item.SelectSingleNode("v4:RatedShipmentDetails/v4:ShipmentRateDetail/v4:TotalNetCharge/v4:Amount").text shows an error: Object Required: 'SelectSingleNode(...)'

Comment: Please edit your question and post a valid XML response. I will use that as the example. The version you posted was not well-formed, hence why I didn't use it.

Comment: Alright, I figured it out.  item.SelectSingleNode("rate:RatedShipmentDetails/rate:ShipmentRateDetail/rate:TotalNetCharge/rate:Amount").text  should be  item.SelectSingleNode("rate:RatedShipmentDetails/rate:ShipmentRateDetail[rate:RateType='PAYOR_LIST_PACKAGE']/rate:TotalNetCharge/rate:Amount").text... you may or may not need an @ symbol in front of rate: for the code in the square brackets!

Comment: Glad you were able to figure it out